# ZendSkeleton 404 error - The requested URL could not be matched by routing

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404, zend-route

So I've been following the fairly straightforward zend 2 skeleton example "album". I followed every step to the teeth and yet I cannot escape the **404 Error - requested URL could not be matched by routing** whenever I input http://hostname/album for indexing, or http://hostname/album/add for adding, etc.

Naturally I looked into the routing found in the **module.config.php** file:

```
 <?php
 return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
     ),
 ),
 'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'album' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),
 'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
);
```

Everything here looked fine, so I looked into the **Module.php** where the **module.config.php** is getting loaded from:

```
 <?php
  namespace Album;

  use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
  use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

  class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
  {
      public function getAutoloaderConfig()
      {
         return array(
         'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
             __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
         ),
         'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
             'namespaces' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
             ),
         ),
     );
     }

     public function getConfig()
     {
          return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
     }
  }
```

Again, everything looks fine here. Now I thought maybe the problem is that I didn't include the Album module in the **application.config.php** file (comments removed):

```
<?php
return array(

'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Album',
),

'module_listener_options' => array(

    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),

    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
    ),

);
```

However it is included. I also have the **AlbumController.php** and the view (.phtml) files exactly where they should be. I double checked the paths multiple times yet the routes still do not work. Any ideas? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

PS - I am using a Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual Box.

EDIT

Here's the directory structure for the application: (I'm just listing the relevant files/folders to make it more readable)

- ZendSkel

  - public

    - index.php
  - config

    - application.config.php
  - module

    - Application
    - Album

      - Module.php
      - config

        - module.config.php
      - src

        - Album

          - Controller

            - AlbumController.php
          - Model
          - Form
      - view

        - album

          - album

            - index.phtml
            - add.phtml
            - edit.phtml
            - delete.phtml

Also, I am using virtual host with apache2.2.

Comment: All looks fine to me. Are you sure about your folder structure? Are all the files at the correct place according to [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html#setting-up-the-album-module) structure?

Comment: I listed the directory structure just now. I double-checked the directory structure numerous times and I'm pretty sure it's fine.

Comment: You say " I also have the `AlbumController.php` and the view (.phtml) files exactly where they should be." however, in the directory structure you  listed you have an `ApplicationController.php` where the `AlbumController.php` should be. Is that a typo, or the source of your 404 problem?

Comment: Ops @Crisp sorry for that, it's just a typo. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, who is still looking for solution of this problem,

Clearing the **data/cache** folder, allowed routing to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mayank Awasthi said:

> Clearing the **data/cache** folder, allowed routing to work as
> expected.

This applies to Zend **AND** Laminas.

If the issue is not cache related, check your config and routing files!

Answer (score 0):

If you follwoing the tutorial in the official page step by step and it shows 404. make sure 1- stop the serve,
2- enter "composer development-enable".
3- enter "composer serve"
and then it should work. The tutorial does mention "composer development-enable" but it doesnt mention it in the right order, reason why a lot of people keep getting the 404